# NameError in Soap Python response by php curl

Tags: php, python, curl, soap

i wrote a script, that should call a simple soap service (in python) to receive datas. The url requires get parameters, to work fine.

I realized the request with php curl:

```
<?php
            // Curl Init
            $ch = $curlObject;

            // Set URL
            $url = "http://localhost/soapService/?";

            // Add get params
            $url .= http_build_query(array("article" => "[($articleNR, 5)]"));

            // Fill curl
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Execute
            $serverOutput = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

But the response says:

```
"NameError: name 'article' is not defined"
```

And if i call the URL directly in my browser, everything works fine. Where is the magic?

Comment: Trace HTTP headers in your browser, then trace HTTP request headers in CURL. Comparing them will give you the answer

Comment: @hindmost - clever one, i tried this. But same effect as before. I've add everything in webbrowsers request header into my php curl header without any successs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, just made it! There was a missing CURL PARAM

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); // Now everything works fine!
```

Comment: I think its making sense.